# Magento 2, On checkout page: Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding

Tags: magento2

I am facing this issue on checkout page of Magento. It where we load Shipping methods. I can't see any workaround for the same.

```
knockout.js:3381 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return shippingRateGroups }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return $parent.getRatesForGroup($data) }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return carrier_code !='vendor_rates' }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return (available) }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return method_title }"
Message: method_title is not defined
    at text (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2982), <anonymous>:3:57)
    at update (knockout.js:4659)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3373)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2173)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2140)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2101)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1954)
    at knockout.js:3371
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:159)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3343)
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, 
Actually I'm verifying address book restricted status(Which is disabled from backend admin), And I'm trying to validate it, But I face only this error.
https://i.imgur.com/dvR9XPP.png

Comment: Don't know what should I have to update in order to resolve this issue.
https://i.imgur.com/dvR9XPP.png


Anyone has a solution, Then please share it here.